# Phonegap and Google maps on Blackberry

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3, blackberry-webworks

I'm trying to create a simple application which uses Google maps to display a map of the locations the user has searched for. I have created a Phonegap project in Eclipse and it runs very well in Android and iPhone but the maps do not render in Blackberry. The Blackberry I am using to test on is a Bold 9700, which has been upgraded from OS v5 to OS v6. I have modified my config.xml to allow the mobile to access "*" subdomains. When I run my code, I make a call to Google maps using my key and I make sure to include a callback function so that my code can continue after Google maps has loaded.

The problem is, when the application is launched on the Blackberry Bold, the map page loads and does absolutely nothing. On the other hand, when the map page loads on Android and iPhone platforms, I see that the callback has been called by Google maps. I really have no idea as to why this problem is happening only on Blackberry... I have researched this problem only to find suggestions that I have already tried. I know I'm missing something but I can't figure out what it is.

This is my HTML code:

```
<body onload="init()">
   <div id="map_canvas">
   </div>
</body>
```

And this is my Javascript code:

```
function init(){     
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GoogleMapKey&sensor=false&callback=codeAddress";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

In my `codeAddress` callback method, the first thing I do is `alert("hello")` just to make sure that `codeAddress` has been called. On Android and iPhone, I see the alert. I then assign the map to the div element. The problem I'm having is that Blackberry doesn't seem to be contacting Google maps, and therefore not executing the callback when Google maps is done loading.

I was curious so I also tried a static map and I did not have any luck there either. Are there some permissions that I am forgetting? This is what I have in my config.xml:

```
  <access subdomains="true" uri="http://gstatic.com"/>
  <access subdomains="true" uri="http://google.com"/>
  <access subdomains="true" uri="http://googleapis.com"/>
  <access subdomains="true" uri="*"/>
```

I've also read that BB OS v5 does not support Google maps as well as the newer versions of the OS, hence the upgraded Blackberry Bold test device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, when building 'ant blackberry build' command, the build command looks for a config.xml file to set proper permissions and access rights. Phonegap's online build website also uses a config.xml to properly configure the app but the syntax of these two config.xml files are not exactly the same. Where i had:

```
  <access subdomains="true" uri="http://gstatic.com"/>
  <access subdomains="true" uri="http://google.com"/>
  <access subdomains="true" uri="http://googleapis.com"/>
  <access subdomains="true" uri="*"/>
```

i should have had

```
  <access subdomains="true" origin="http://www.gstatic.com"/>
  <access subdomains="true" origin="http://www.google.com"/>
  <access subdomains="true" origin="http://www.googleapis.com"/>
```

the syntax of these try xml files are similar but not exactly the same. As soon as i made this change, i was able to get a static map to work. My next step is to try and get a dynamic map to work but at least i know a static map does work.

This is the [link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/blackberrys_config_xml_doesnt_works_in_phonegap_build) that i followed to come to this conclusion